# Position div relative to a table cell on the page that is zoomed

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to place an absolutely positioned div with a tooltip right below the table cell when you doubletap on it.

So what i was doing:
-get the position of the cell itself:

```
var cell_pos_top = $(this).offset().top;
var cell_pos_left = $(this).offset().left;
```

-then when user use doubletap position div accordingly:

```
$("#tooltip_div").css('top', cell_pos_top + 22).css('left', cell_pos_left - 2)
```

Everything works fine for me when I view the page on desktop computer, however when i do this on smartphone & page is zoomed my div is no longer positioned right below the cell. Looks like if the page is zoomed & moved off-center, CSS top & left properties starting to count from the edge of the browser window instead of the page itself.

Comment: You could prevent zooming by setting the zoom options in the viewport meta tag.

Comment: Zooming is required, therefore cannot be disabled. I'm looking for a workaround.